# Control stability problem

Tags: control-theory

Design controllers $u_1$ depending on $x$ and $u_2$ depending on $y$ such that the following system is exponentially stable:
$$\dot x = A_1 x + B_1 u_1  + C_1 y \\
\dot y = A_2 y + B_2 u_2  + C_2 x \\$$
where ($A_1$, $B_1$) and ($A_2$, $B_2$) are stabilizable, respectively, and $C_1  \ne 0$, $C_2 \ne 0.$

Comment: Technically, $u_i$ is not controller, it is input signal. By $u_1$ depending on $x$, do you mean $u_1=K_1 x$?

Comment: Yes, I think so.